# Android notification vibration does not stop after cancelling

Tags: android, notifications, vibration

I am trying to implement audio/video calls notification, like it works in Telegram. I have a problem with vibration. It does not stop after cancelling notification and after timeout. A sound stops. Only rebooting my phone helps. I tried lot's of things. I want my vibration pattern to repeat until the notification is cancelled. Here is my code for creating the channel:

```
        fun createCallChannel(context: Context, channelID: String){
        val callChannel = NotificationChannel(
            channelID,
            "Call",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH // for heads-up notifications
        )
        callChannel.description = "call channel"
        callChannel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC

        val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .build()

 // when i use this commented line, vibrations does not work at all. Why?
    //    val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE).build()

        val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE)
        callChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes)
        callChannel.enableVibration(true)

        val vibrationPattern = LongArray(2) { 500 }
        callChannel.vibrationPattern = vibrationPattern

        val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        manager.createNotificationChannel(callChannel)
    }
```

Here is my code for creating the notification:

```
 val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder =
                            NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ChannelsUtils.CHANNEL_CALL_ID)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_push_notification)
                                .setColor(rootAccentColor)
                                .setContentTitle(getString(contentTitleId))
                                .setContentText(fio)
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE))
                                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                .setOngoing(true)
                                .setAutoCancel(false)
                                .setTimeoutAfter(60 * 1000)
                                .addAction(
                                    0,
                                    getString(R.string.answer), answerCallPendingIntent
                                )
                                .addAction(
                                    0,
                                    getString(R.string.cancel), declineCallPendingIntent
                                )
                                .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)

                        val notification = notificationBuilder.build()
                        notification.flags = notification.flags or Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT// i use this flag to repeat sound and vibration
                        notificationManager.notify(
                            NotificationBroadcastReceiver.CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                            notification
                        )
```

This way i cancel the notification:

```
    private val notificationManager by lazy { getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java) }
            notificationManager.cancel(NotificationBroadcastReceiver.CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID)
```

Please help.